# How can I dart pub publish on travis ci deploy

Tags: dart, travis-ci, dart-pub

I would like to know if anyone can provide a nice answer to:

How can I publish a dart package on https://pub.dartlang.org/ during the deploy step, for example on a certain tag or even specified branch?

I have figured that I can run a script as a provider but I assume that the access token is required for pub I guess? Its not super clear so then I decided to ask here. For even more detailed context, my project is [here](https://github.com/lessonteacher/shellstone) and I would like to tag a release and have it publish like npm release.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I found that the following did solve the issue...

1. Added a section to the `.travis.yml` to set the deploy script, I changed to branch just for this example since I messed up the tag example

```
  deploy:
    provider: script
    script: ./tool/publish.sh
    on:
      branch: master
```

2. Setup some `publish.sh` that writes the json out

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p .pub-cache

cat <<EOF > ~/.pub-cache/credentials.json
{
  "accessToken":"$accessToken",
  "refreshToken":"$refreshToken",
  "tokenEndpoint":"$tokenEndpoint",
  "scopes":["$scopes"],
  "expiration":$expiration
}
EOF

pub publish -f
```

3. Set the env variables in travis settings for the repo with the show in build disabled.

Only thing now is if it will work after expiry...

Comment: After a few days now I have pushed a tagged release to master and it did deploy to pub without any issue with token freshness so this this answer is confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the tag or branch, then you can publish using `pub publish` from that directory. You would need to make the `~/.pub-cache/credentials.json` to the travis instance.

I haven't tried it myself. There might be additional requirements.

Comment: Hmm thanks thats a bit of help as I didn't even know of the file so guess a potential strategy could be to put the tokens into env vars, write the credentials file out on the deploy. Problem i assume is that it looks like the token is 24hrs access before needs a refresh

Comment: It's created by `pub uploader` where a web page is opened to login AFAIR and then the file is generated. I never had to do anything since then. I think it gets updated automatically when it expired.

Comment: Ok good news, thanks for your help it was perfect. I was able to solve this problem so I will provide an answer.